# diffing two .env files

Tags: shell, environment-variables, diff

I have two env files, let's say x.env and y.env, the order of the variables is different, but the content could be the same but likely different.

Is there some tool I could use to diff the variables?

```
   env -i (
    # clear all envs
     source x.env;
     env | sort >  x.sh
    )

   env -i (
    # clear all envs
     source y.env;
     env | sort >  y.sh
    )

    diff x.sh y.sh
```

is that just about the best way? if there are multiple ones missing, it might make diffing noisy and not very useful, whereas comparing variable names one-by-one might be better..

Comment: `man comm` may be of some help on your sorted files. Good luck.

Comment: After reading the sentence "the order of the variables is different, but the content could be the same but likely different", I'm not sure I know what's the same and what's different.  Are the variable _names_ the same, but their _values_ are different?  Do you want to catch cases like that? Or are you more interested in whether a particular variable is missing in one of the files, no matter their values?

Comment: With `diff -u`, the reports of deleted variables should be readable. They will appear as lines prefixed with `-` (minus). There is syntax coloring support for that in editors.  Plus you have other options for diff tools, like `meld` or whatever.

Comment: @Kaz how is diff going to handle things that are out of order? could have same key/values but different order. Would appreciate an upvote if you understand.

Comment: Your `x.sh` and `y.sh` are sorted; I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Kaz the question is how to diff two env files, that's all, the best way to do it

Comment: Right, so you have `diff` in your solution. Make it `diff -u` for something that is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running `bash` or another shell that allows inline command redirection,

```
comm -3 <(sort x.env) <(sort y.env)
```

Or, to source the variables as shown in your question, you can try this but beware of differences in `LC_*` locale variables that may affect the sorting order - and in turn cause `comm` to complain that the inputs aren't sorted:

```
comm -3 <(. x.env; env | sort) <(. y.env; env | sort)
```

Comment: yeah the files have comments so the source command is better