# Group results using comm

Tags: bash, shell, diff, comm

Using `comm` I get results that look weird from this:

```
comm -3 <(. "$first_env_file"; env) <(. "$second_env_file"; env)
```

I get something like:

```
AUTH_LP_ACCOUNT_ID=xxx1
        AUTH_LP_ACCOUNT_ID=xxx2
        AWS_IMAGE_DOMAIN_NAME=abc
AWS_IMAGE_DOMAIN_NAME=zyx
NODE_ENV=local
        NODE_ENV=staging
        NODE_PORT=3000
NODE_PORT=4000
REDIS_HOST=localhost
        REDIS_HOST=redis
```

(and yes the spaces in front (prepended tabs/spaces) are there)

what I would rather it look like is something like this:

```
--begin--
AUTH_LP_ACCOUNT_ID=xx1
AUTH_LP_ACCOUNT_ID=xx2
---------
AWS_IMAGE_DOMAIN_NAME=abc
AWS_IMAGE_DOMAIN_NAME=zyx
---------
NODE_ENV=local
NODE_ENV=staging
---------
NODE_PORT=3000
NODE_PORT=4000
---------
REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_HOST=redis
---end---
```

is there a way to accomplish this?

1. to remove prepended lines we can pipe through `sed 's/^ *//.
2. putting `--begin--` and `---end---` at begin/end is easy matter
3. but how to group results easily?

My only guess at 3 is to loop over each line (skipping first) and if the next result has a different xxx= vs abc= then print a `--------` but I am not in love with that.

Comment: `comm` means the results must all be sorted; but is your example representative, or are there sometimes variables that show up *only* in one or the other environment?

Comment: @Wildcard the [original solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/758066/100397) did include `sort`

Comment: @ChrisDavies then `comm` output is unspecified.  It requires sorted input.  So that's a bug in the original solution; the inputs should be changed e.g. `<(. "$first_env_file"; env | sort)`

Comment: @Wildcard I think you've misread what I wrote

Comment: @ChrisDavies d'oh!  Yes I did, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My only guess at 3 is to loop over each line (skipping first) and if the next result has a different xxx= vs abc= then print a -------- but I am not in love with that.

Your guess is just fine.  Do it in awk.

```
comm ... | sed 's/^\t//' | awk -F= 'NR == 1 {cur = $1; print "---- begin ----"} cur != $1 {print "---------"} {cur = $1; print} END {print "---- end ----"}'
```

With line breaks added for readability:

```
comm ... | sed 's/^\t//' | awk -F= '
NR == 1 {
  cur = $1;
  print "---- begin ----"
}
cur != $1 {
  print "---------"
}
{
  cur = $1;
  print
}
END {
  print "---- end ----"
}'
```

Output on the provided sample:

```
---- begin ----
AUTH_LP_ACCOUNT_ID=xxx1
AUTH_LP_ACCOUNT_ID=xxx2
---------
AWS_IMAGE_DOMAIN_NAME=abc
AWS_IMAGE_DOMAIN_NAME=zyx
---------
NODE_ENV=local
NODE_ENV=staging
---------
NODE_PORT=3000
NODE_PORT=4000
---------
REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_HOST=redis
---- end ----
```